# Why cant we instantiate an interface but can do an array of interface?

Tags: java, interface

For example, this is valid and we need to have Class Two objects in this T array, what is the purpose of this acceptance?

```
interface One 
{
    public void callback();   
}

class Two implements One
{
    One[] T = new One[5];
}
```

Comment: Because an interface without an implementation is useless - where is the impl coming from? - but an array of interfaces is use*ful*: you can put different implementations in the array.

Comment: The interface represents a Type. You are creating an Array of a Type in this case the Type is your interface. The Array can hold any object that is an implementation of your interface.

Comment: Thanks @Michael, I am a beginner in Java, so unless I see the real time usage of the OOPs concepts, these are only rules for me, hope to learn more

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you aren't instantiating an interface, you are instantiating an array. No interfaces are instantiated here:

```java
One[] T = new One[5];
```

Every element of `T` will be `null`. Creating an instance could look like this:

```java
class OneImpl implements One {
   @Override
   public void callback() {
      System.out.println("callback");
   }
}

T[0] = new OneImpl();
```

Or like this:

```java
T[0] = new One() { 
    @Override
    public void callback() {
        System.out.println("callback");
    }
};
```

Or even like this:

```java
T[0] = () -> System.out.println("callback");
```

Comment: Thanks @erickson, I am a beginner in Java, so unless I see the real time usage of the OOPs concepts, these are only rules for me, hope to learn more